# Java 8 access previous value in Nested Lists

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have following class

```
class Customer {
  List<String> itemCodes;
  String customerId;
}
```

Lets say I have List of customers and I need to search the customerId of a first customer in this list with a specific itemCode.

The way I do currently is as follows

```
    for (Customer cust : Customers) {
            if (cust.getItemCodes() != null && cust.getItemCodes().contains("SPECIFIC_CODE")) {
                return cust.getCustomerId();
            }
}
```

I wanted to convert above loop using Java8

The best I could get right now is

```
customers.stream().flatMap(cust -> cust.getItemCodes().stream()).filter(code -> code.equals("SPECIFIC_CODE")).findFirst();
```

But this returns me Optional with value as a item code itself. But I need the customerId of that person. Problem is, I am not sure how I can access previous value of lambda here?

So is there any way I can use java8 to replace above loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `flatMap` here. Just use `filter` to locate  matching `Customer` and `map` to obtain the `CustomerId` of that `Customer`.

```
return customers.stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getItemCodes() != null && c.getItemCodes().contains("SPECIFIC_CODE"))
                .map(Customer::getCustomerId)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null); // default value in case no match is found
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! was close yet so far :)